# Unit Test Formatting of Word/Phrase in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor

I'd like to write a test in my project that specifically looks at the HTML and tells me if every instance of a word is always formatted a certain way. Let's say our company has a product named "WidgetFactory". I want to make sure that this "WidgetFactory" is always capitalized the same way, and is always within a `<strong>` tag.

I'm not sure what the best practice in Unit Testing is. I've glanced at precompiled views, but it never looked quite right. It might be the best solution. I might could open each .cshtml file and try to parse it so that I only look at HTML text, but that could be potentially problematic and I don't really want to write a Razor parser.

Is this possible, or is this a completely wrong way of using a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of tests should be done in Integration Tests, not unit tests. You don't want to run it everytime you run your other tests, only before you push to prod, and idealy in a continuous integration system like [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or [appveyor](http://www.appveyor.com/). You could use a tool like [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) that open a browser (like Chrome) and verify that the end result contains the text the way you want it to be.

I suggest you take a look at the [page pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) it really helped us.

Here's what one sample test could look like, note that we have a lot of helper to make the tests clean and easy to read/maintain :

```
[Test]
    public void CreateViewAndEditShouldWork()
    {
        S.OpenWithCI();
        var loginPage = new LoginPage(S);
        var centerListPage = loginPage
            .LoginValidUser("username", "password")
            .MenuClickCenterAndRoomLink();
        var centerPage = centerListPage.ClickCreateLink();

        //Create
        centerPage.Submit();
        Assert.That(centerPage.Error("Name"), Is.StringContaining(Strings.Error_Required));
        Assert.That(centerPage.Error("EnglishName"), Is.StringContaining(Strings.Error_Required));

        centerPage.Name = "Saguenay";
        centerPage.EnglishName = "Sag";
        centerPage.Address = "2089 blv Talbot";
        centerPage.DivisionAfiSelected = true;
        centerPage.Submit();

        centerListPage.ExpectSuccessNotice(Strings.CenterCreatedSuccessfully);

        //View
        var centerDetailsPage = centerListPage.ClickDetailsLink("Saguenay");
        Assert.That(centerDetailsPage.Title, Is.StringContaining("SAGUENAY"));
        Assert.That(centerDetailsPage.Details, Is.StringContaining("Inactive"));
        Assert.That(centerDetailsPage.Details, Is.StringContaining("2089 blv Talbot"));

        //Edit
        centerPage = centerDetailsPage.ClickEdit();
        centerPage.Name = "Chicoutimi";

        centerPage.Submit();
        centerListPage.ExpectSuccessNotice(Strings.CenterUpdatedSuccessfully);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good info! I'm pretty new to testing (other than run and try it manually), but I'll have to do some research on Integration Tests. Thanks!